# Incremental Display does not work with R Presentation

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

The bullet points in "First Slide" do now show one by one. I used the `incremental: true`. Why did the option not work?

Here is my code.

```
design
    ========================================================
author: y
date: 2017-12-18
autosize: true
incremental: true
transition: rotate
transition-speed: slow

First Slide
========================================================
incremental: true
type: section

* 1
* 2
* 3
```

Here is my session info

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[5] datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 tools_3.4.3    yaml_2.1.16
```

**Edit**: Someone online wrote, if `section` and `subsection` were used in `type`, incremental display would not work. He said it in 2014. Now is 2017 December. Three years have passed. It seems that RStudio will not fix this in near future.

I got recommendation to use other packages to create slides, such as,

- https://yihui.name/en/2017/08/xaringan-incremental-slides/
- http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-11.html

Comment: Incremental content rendering does not work on title slides.

Comment: For incremental slides, I haven't seen a more flexible framework than remark.js: https://yihui.name/en/2017/08/xaringan-incremental-slides/

Comment: @YihuiXie Thank you. Your example representation has an impressive the last slide.